# Export class vs. export function for creation

Tags: javascript

I notice some libraries expose a function to user for creating instance, while some other expose a class directly. For example, **Vue.js** uses `new Vue(...)` to create a new instance, and **Express.js** uses `express()` to initialize. Currently I am writing a libary for my company, and I cannot decide which one I should choose. What are the pros and cons of these two design style? And what should I prefer to use?

Comment: Some people just don't like using `new`. There are various reasons for this including just personal preference. You might expose a function if you want to preserve internal mechanisms, e.g., if you have a factory. Ultimately, the syntax doesn't really matter as much as the *goal* you want to achieve.

Comment: It does not really matter in Node.js. A lot of this things are done historically, because before ES6 (released in 2015) defining class was syntax-hell and lot of developers preffered to use pure functions instead.

Comment: @libik People still prefer plain functions if they don't need `class` inheritance, or when they are wrapping the instantiation for extra initialisation that doesn't happen in a constructor

Comment: @libik I feel like the pure function usage has *risen* since ES6 was introduced. Partly because of more popularity but also in general, I don't think it was as widespread to think of JS in terms of functional computation.

Comment: @VLAZ - well it depends which part of Node.js app you want to develop. All the common web frameworks and middlewares are functions based and it does not make much sense to write it as classes. Similar to all services, controllers, repositories - you want singleton-like behaviour anyway, so why bother with classes there. However at the end of the chain, using classes make sense - i.e. instance of Redis connection, instance of your document you got from DB...

Comment: I like your question, it can bring in more discussion about design patterns.
For exporting a class, generally means users can freely instantiate the instance and do not need to concern about correlating with other parties. But for exporting a function which also produce an instance, apparently a factory method, it means the library doesn't want to let users create an istnc by themselves to avoid unexpected consequence. There r some considerations about initiation or correlating with related parties, for example, putting the instance in a pool managed by the library.

Comment: @Wenbo there is a lot to discuss about this question which makes it unsuitable for Stack Overflow. We aim to solve concrete problems with clearly defined parameters. Unfortunately, "whether or not I should use `new`" has no single answer by itself. There are many arguments for and against it. Just as an example, there is [New Considered Harmful](https://wiki.c2.com/?NewConsideredHarmful) as well as a *plethora* of discussions on the subject under the same title (because people seem to want to borrow authenticity from Mr. Dijkstra). Ultimately, most times it doesn't really matter, either.